# enviar un array a php con el valor de un input file

Tags: javascript, php

espero puedan ayudarme ya que no se que hacer,

tengo un array de objetos el cual se arma de la siguiente manera

```
     let warranty = {};
      warranty.description = document.getElementById("txt_description").value;
      warranty.brand = document.getElementById("txt_marca").value;
      warranty.serie = document.getElementById("txt_serie").value;
      warranty.model = document.getElementById("txt_model").value;
      warranty.color = document.getElementById("txt_color").value;
      warranty.time_use = document.getElementById("txt_year_use").value;
      warranty.status = document.getElementById("dp_status").value;
      warranty.location = document.getElementById("dp_location").value;
      warranty.price = document.getElementById("txt_price").value;
      warranty.img = imgInput.files[0];
```

luego lo agrego al array general que me guarda todos los productos que se han ingresado,

```
warranties.push(warranty);
```

luego lo que contenga ese array trato de enviarlo a php mediante fetch

```
 let datos = new FormData();
 datos.append("data",JSON.stringify(warranties));
 fetch(controller, {
    method: "POST",
    body: datos,
 })
```

lo que recibo en el fetch es
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ayuda!!!!

Comment: y no es eso lo que esperas? Si el problema está relacionado con las imágenes, debes indicar de que manera quieres recibir las imagenes, pero en lo demás no veo ningún problema

Comment: ¿que es imgInput?  ¿Y que quieres guardar?  ¿su nombre?  ¿no sería más bien `files[0].name`?

Comment: el detalles es que no logro acceder a las imagenes, lo que es pero es poder mover las fotos a mi servidor, pero si le doy $_FILES[data[img]] me dice index no encontrado

Comment: imginput es el campo tipo file, lo que quiero es que que pueda enviar el archivo como tal, para poder manejarlo en el lado de php

Comment: pues ponle otro append así:  `datos.append('img', imgInput.files[0]);` a ver si cuela... se que parece lo mismo, pero en [esta web](https://www.webslesson.info/2021/06/file-upload-in-javascript-using-fetch-api-with-php.html) lo hacen así y les parece funcionar.  Quizás tu problema esté en lo que es `imgInput` que no vemos en ninguna parte de tu pregunta y no sabemos seguro si lo haces bien por eso.

Comment: Si lo consigues hacer funcionar gracias a la info de esa web, coge y postea tu mismo la respuesta que te ha funcionado para que la comunidad lo sepa, gracias.